# django - use filter in the argument to a simple_tag

Tags: python, django

I had a custom simple-tag. And it seems I can't use a filter as its argument.

Here is an example. `mysum` is the tag. `myincrease` is the filter. `foobar` is a variable and I want to pass `foobar|myincrease` to `mysum`.

The template:

```
{% mysum foobar|myincrease 1 2 %}
```

gives the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [foobar|myincrease] in ...
```

The tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def mysum(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c
```

The filter:

```
@register.filter
def myincrease(num):
    return num + 1
```

I have worked around my original problem using other approaches. But I'm still wondering if this is by design, or a mistake of mine, or a bug of django, or something that has been overlooked.

I think calling something like `compile_filter` in the `simple_tag` decorator implementation would do it.

Comment: Did you found an answer by yourself ? I'm facing the same problem ^^

Comment: Sorry I don't quite remember now. I think I ended up using the workaround.

Comment: Seems a django-specific issue: reproducible in 1.3.1, works in 1.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Though it doesn't appear to be mentioned in the ticket, it looks like the fixing of https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13956 added filter support to positional arguments to a tag. You can see the commit at https://github.com/django/django/commit/8137027f - the new `parse_bits` function called `compile_filter()` on positional arguments.

Another workaround would be to use the `{% with %}` tag.